# React/Redux need help removing items from a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is a super noob question, I'm learning redux and it's capabilities. However, I'm stuck while trying to remove an item from a list. This list has items added to it via a JSON object I imported and that is pushed into an array which I later loop through.

In one component I add the prices(mock data) through button clicks and I have a total (sum of the prices) working. This action also adds the name to the side list.

I've been searching but haven't found a good solution. I was hoping someone here can help me understand and/or point me in the right direction.

So far when I click the button it adds an empty button to the list instead than removing. Correct me if I'm wrong but this is the intended behavior for the slice function, to return an array?

Here is my initial state:

```
const initialState = [{   
    name: '',
    total: '',
}]
```

My action type:

```
case ActionTypes.REMOVE_EXAMS:
       return[
            ...state[0].name.slice(0, action.index),
            ...state[0].name.slice(action.index + 1)
        ]

case ActionTypes.ADD_PRICES:
        return   [
        { 
            total: Number(state[0].total + action.price),
            name: action.name
         }
        ]
```

This is the component that renders a side list with all the items that have been added. My idea is to press the button and remove that item permanently from this side list

```
static propTypes = {
    dataCarryName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    removeExams: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    total: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.names = [];
}

render() {

    {this.names.push(this.props.dataCarryName)}
    {console.log(this.names)}
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
         <div className="side-exam-view">
         <Paper zDepth={2}>
            <h1> Carrito </h1>
            {this.props.total}
            {this.names.map((i, k) => {
                return(
                    <ul key={k}
                         className="exam-list-names">
                        <li key={k}>
                        <button onClick={() => this.props.removeExams(( i.length, {i}))}> {i} - X</button>
                        </li>
                        <Divider />
                    </ul>
                )
            })}
        </Paper>
    </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
    );      
}}
```

**Update:**
These are my action creators:

```
export const addPrices = (price, name) => {
return{
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_PRICES,
    price,
    name
}}
export const removeExams = (index, name) => {
return {
    type: ActionTypes.REMOVE_EXAMS,
    index,
    name
}}
```

Comment: You haven't shown what your `removeExams` action creator looks like, that might be helpful.

Comment: @Samo just added them, sorry about that. Hope this gives more insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I see at least a couple issues here and hopefully dealing with them will help you solve your problem.

First, I'm not sure that the way you're keeping your sum makes sense. I think what you really want to do is maintain a list of exams where each exam has a name and a price. You also want to be able to display the list of exam names and also the sum of the prices. So for starters I think your reducer should look more like this.

```
const initialState = [];

export default function reduce(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.ADD_EXAM:
      return state.concat({ name: action.name, price: action.price });
    case ActionTypes.REMOVE_EXAM:
      return state.filter(exam => exam.name === action.name)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

So `ADD_EXAM` adds a new entry to your array with a name and a price, and `REMOVE_EXAM` looks for the exam specified by `action.name` and filters it out.

You can easily display your sum like this:

```
const sum = exams.reduce((sum, exam) => sum + exam.price, 0);
```

And you can display your names like this:

```
const names = exams.map((exam, index) => <p key={index}>{exam.name}</p>);
```